# Translate array values write to file php

Tags: php, arrays, translation, google-translate, fwrite

I have a google language translate PHP class you can see [here](http://www.codediesel.com/php/google-translation-php-wrapper/)

My array file like this:

```
$lang['FORUM_LOCK'] = 'Lock';
$lang['FORUM_EDIT'] = 'Edit';
$lang['FORUM_POST'] ='Post';
```

...

I want to loop through and translate all array values and write to file.
I tried all kinds of methods but cant figure it out :(

Im sure someone has done this before?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a `foreach` construct to iterate through all values of `$lang`.

Something like this :

```
$lang_fr = array();
foreach($lang as $key => $val) {
    $lang_fr = $gt->translate($val , "en", "fr");
}
```

You can write then it to a PHP file using `fwrite()` using the same construct :

```
fwrite($fp, "\$lang_fr['$key'] ='$val';\n");
```

Be wary of specials characters though. [You may want to use `addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Comment: Thats, thats pretty much what i had..  but want to save to a file and keep the array the same  $lang['FORUM_POST'] ='translated'; <--etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend Google Translate class:

```
class ExtendedTranslate extends GoogleTranslateWrapper {
   public function translateArray($array, $fromLanguage, $toLanguage) {
      foreach ($array as &$item) {
         $item = $this->translate($item, $fromLanguage, $toLanguage);
      }
      return array();
   }
}
```